# Type parameter not required in Java generic class?

Tags: java, generics

Consider a plain-old generic class:

```
class Blob<T>{
    T peanut;
}
```

To my surprise, the following line of code compiled okay:

```
Blob c=new Blob();
```

Why is this allowed, and what type is automatically inserted?

Comment: in generics you can use raw types, which is a very bad idea btw

Comment: your IDE should at least warns you about: ***Blob is a raw type. References to generic type Blob<T> should be parameterized***

Comment: You are allowed to this to maintain back-compatibility with Java code before 1.5. If you don't know what ```T``` could be you should use ```?``` like so in the variable type declaration: ```Blob<?> c```. You cannot use ```?``` in the new clause because there is no way you cannot come out with an appropriate type-parameter since you are the one instantiating it. The minimum common denominator here is using Object: ```new Blob<Object>()```.

Comment: In this case you know that ```c``` is actually ```Blob<Object>``` so is preferable that you declare it like so instead of ```Blob<?>```. If you do that then since 1.7 (I think) you can omit the type-parameter in the constructor as it is automatically deduced by the compiler. Thus most likely what you want to write here is: ```Blob<Object> c = new Blob<>();```